# How does bidirectional operator work for (g)awk?

Tags: awk

I have been looking at the bidirectional operator in awk and been trying to understand it.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO

So I tried this in .awk file,

```
BEGIN {
cmd="tr [a-z] [A-Z]"
print "hi" |& cmd
close(cmd,"to")
cmd |& getline
close(cmd)
}
```

found here, https://books.google.se/books?id=NrZTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=bidirectional+pipeline+awk+example&source=bl&ots=awgGmpZBxm&sig=ACfU3U0jxy2GO2qaUb-gCOrP9CmrC3SsYA&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijw8i267viAhXq-ioKHRyWDwMQ6AEwC3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=bidirectional%20pipeline%20awk%20example&f=false

This looks quite fine, so I tried to modify it,

```
BEGIN {
cmd="ssh some_server"
print "ls /some/file" |& cmd
close(cmd,"to")
cmd |& getline
print $0
close(cmd)
}
```

This fails quite good though. I manages to login and get the banner. Then I get the message,

> Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).

Followed by the program terminates. However, the "ls" command is not running. Anyone who know what I have missed?

**EDIT**

I also tried

```
BEGIN {
cmd="ssh some_server"
print "ls /some/file" |& cmd
cmd |& getline
print $0
close(cmd)
}
```

without closing the stream in one of the directions. The result is unpredictable. It either hangs or fails the same way. It does at least not work.

Running "ssh server ls /some/file" works fine though, so I suspect it is a awk piping to bash/tcsh issue.

**EDIT2**

There are a lot of other suggestions here, so I think I need to update my questions. Sometimes it seems as an MVCE may cause more problems that it helps...

Anyway, the idea is to start an ssh session to which I can keep sending new commands until I am done and then the close the ssh session. So the idea was to initiate an ssh shell session and then pipe commands to it and read replies with this operator.

```
BEGIN {
cmd="ssh some_server"
print "ls /some/file" |& cmd
cmd |& getline
print $0
print "some other command" |& cmd
cmd |& getline
close(cmd)
}
```

Also, there are other options which can be considered, but none which will be easy.

**EDIT3**

Thinks I will restart this here.

What I want to do is to start an ssh session with the ssh client coming with the standard linux RHEL7 distribution. Then I want to keep the session open while I keep sending commands to it. When I am done I need to terminate the session. From bash it would looks something like this,

```
ssh host
command1
command2
exit
```

A requirement is that this is done by pure awk scripting. All other options would just create more problems in the future. Note username being left out. This is currently handled in our environment and doing `ssh 10.10.10.10` works perfectly fine.

BR
Patrik

Comment: `close(cmd,"to")` closes `cmd`'s stdin, thus it fails. Don't do that

Comment: @oguzismail I figured so as well, but without this line it hangs.

Comment: Hmm, Idk. Maybe you should pass the command to ssh from `cmd` like `ssh some_server 'ls ...'` and capture the output with a regular pipe.

Comment: @patrik, IMHO; though I am not sure about your complete requirement but to work with ssh(remote servers mgmt) Ansible is GREAT choice, I had recently done few automation in it, try it out it will be very easy to deal with remote server mgmt work.

Comment: Why do you need some remote process running constantly that you can send commands to anyway rather than simply calling `ssh ... command` every time you want to execute a command on the remote machine?

Comment: @EdMorton The machine in question is not running linux. What I am going to do is actually to run NETCONF over SSH. The standard used requires the ssh connection to always be open. The very simplest case is the candidate capability. There we have an <edit-config>some config</edit-config> followed by a <commit/>. If the session is closed before commit the change will be reset. The reason why I need to use awk is because the whole tool is written in awk. There is quite a few lines and complicated parts, so rewriting it would cost millions and is not realistic. Anyway, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Sounds like you have a Frankenstein's monster on your hands. If/when you want it rewritten in shell+awk, let me know and I won't charge you more than 1 million ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That's not how you execute a remote command with ssh, `ssh some_server -t 'command'` is.
2. That's not how you read the output of a co-process with getline, `while ( (cmd |& getline line) > 0 )` is.

Try this, no co-process required:

```
BEGIN {
    cmd = "ssh some_server \047ls /some/file\047"
    while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        print line
    }
    close(cmd)
}
```

Given that you do want to use co-processes, though, you need the ssh to create some process on your remote machine that subsequent commands can be piped to. Maybe spawn a shell? When I've done in the past hasn't involved awk at all but in shell I used

```
coproc ssh_conn { ssh -T ... some_tool_waiting_for_input }
```

to create a remote process and a named pipe to it and afterwards to write to it:

```
printf '%s\0' 'command' >&"${ssh_conn[1]}"
```

and to read it's output:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' resp <&"${ssh_conn[0]}".
```

So you need to figure out that `ssh -T ... some_tool_waiting_for_input` as a starting point for doing this from awk (which I think is a bad idea as managing processes is what shells are designed to do, not what awk is designed to do - manipulate text).

In the above case my remote tools read nul-terminated rather than newline-terminated strings so I can send multi-line text to it. Your requirements may be different.

For security my remote command requires the local one to authenticate itself and won't allow connections from anything except my local command, you may want to consider that rather than spawning a remote shell which then anyone can connect to to execute commands on your remote machine.

Btw, try adding -T to your ssh command to get rid of the `Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor)`.

Comment: Would this not close the session after the command is finished? I am closing it as I exit the program for this example. If I do this for the real example however, the remote system will reset. So I will have to keep the pipe open as long as I need it and when I do not need to send any more commands I close it.

Comment: Yes it will. If you need to not do that then update your question to clarify your requirements and update the example in your question to be more truly representative by creating the script you want directly in shell first, posting that, and THEN we can look at what you'd need to implement the same from awk but it's extremely unlikely that you should be using awk for this task rather than doing the ssh part in shell and calling awk when necessary to process text.

Comment: Done! Anyway, the point with the MVCE was to show that I wanted to initiate a ssh session and use the bi-directional pipe to send commands to the session. Maybe I explained it too sloppy, but now it is all there at least. Cheers!